# Converter webapp into short url

Tags: .htaccess

Do you know how to rewrite the http://domain .com/application/index.pl into http://app.domain .com ?

I already have the A record on my public DNS server set.

I tried tons of script. 
The running service is CentOS, PHP, PERL and MySQL.

Comment: The beggining of the statement disappeared! But anyway it is clear. I think!

Comment: What you are looking for is a subdomain. You will have to add it to your DNS file and then set " http://domain .com/application/index.pl" as the root view.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an other `<VirtualHost>` config in your Apache config ( assuming you're using Apache). In the `app.domain.com` `<VirtualHost>` section, use `Proxy / http://domain_com/application` to allow access to primary host.

More info about proxying in Apache:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Hi Ibar, do I need to create new VM ? I'm sorry misunderstand. Can you send me some example? I saw the doc recommended however it seems not applicable in that case. I trying some code right now. You can suggest me in order to try it now.

Comment: No need for a new VM, just add new <VirtualHost> definition to current config and new DNS record for app.domain.com with the same IP address than domain.com. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/examples.html